# Compile interface and class in separate files using msc

Tags: c#

I'm getting this error message:

> The type or namespace 'Test_interface' could not be found

when I try to compile one of my classes. Let me be more specific. I have one interface and one class, they are in separate files. The class implements the interface. This is how it looks like:

```
// Test_interface.cs
namespace Boo{
    interface Test_interface{
        void do_something();
    }
}

// Test_class.cs
// I'm not sure whether I should "include" anything here
namespace Boo{
    class Test_class : Test_interface{
        void do_something(){
            // does nothing
        }
        static void Main(){
            // as simple as null
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the way I compile it:

```
$ msc Test_class.cs
```

All this results in an error message, that I mentioned above.

Comment: Don't know msc, but maybe it works similar to [csc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx) - `csc *.cs`

Comment: I.e. *all* (two) files must be compiled into one executable, so that the class "knows" about the interface. --- also, I never remember the default accessability, but I also see no harm in always declaring it a `public interface [...]`.